# Отфильтровать одну таблицу по 2-м условиям из другой таблицы Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Имеется исходная таблица **df1**:

| id | date | city | holiday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-01-18 | Quito | 0 |
| 1 | 2013-01-18 | Manta | 0 |
| 2 | 2013-03-07 | Quito | 0 |
| 3 | 2013-03-07 | Manta | 0 |
| 4 | 2013-05-02 | Quito | 0 |
| 5 | 2013-05-02 | Manta | 0 |

Имеется таблица с местными праздниками **df_events**:

| date | city |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-01-18 | Quito |
| 2013-03-07 | Manta |

Нужно df1 фильтровать по мультиусловиям df_events построчно и в значение holiday записывать 1.

Почему-то этот код не работает, не меняет значения на 1:

```
for i in df_events.index:
    df1[(df1['date'] == df_events['date'][i]) & (df1['city'] == df_events['city'][i])]['holiday'] = 1
```

Этот код работает:

```
ind_hol = []
for i in df_events.index:
    a = df1[(df1['date'] == df_events['date'][i]) & (df1['city'] == df_events['city'][i])].index.values
    if len(a)>0:
        ind_hol.extend(a)
df1.loc[ind_hol]['holiday'] = 1
```

Итоговый результат:

| id | date | city | holiday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-01-18 | Quito | 1 |
| 1 | 2013-01-18 | Manta | 0 |
| 2 | 2013-03-07 | Quito | 0 |
| 3 | 2013-03-07 | Manta | 1 |
| 4 | 2013-05-02 | Quito | 0 |
| 5 | 2013-05-02 | Manta | 0 |

Но основной вопрос, как это можно сделать без цикла, методами Pandas?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос таблицу - как должен выглядеть желаемый результат

Comment: Добавил результат

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете циклы в pandas, значит 95% вы что-то делаете неправильно. я предлагаю такой подход:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df_events, on=["date", "city"])["id"]
# ^^^ здесь вы получаете id тех строк первого датаaрейма,
# которые совпадают в указанных колонках со строками во втором.
df1.loc[res, "holiday"] = 1
# ^^^ а здесь вы по полученному id меняете значение
# в нужной колонке в исходном датафрейме
```

теперь df1:

```
   id        date   city  holiday
0   0  2013-01-18  Quito        1
1   1  2013-01-18  Manta        0
2   2  2013-03-07  Quito        0
3   3  2013-03-07  Manta        1
4   4  2013-05-02  Quito        0
5   5  2013-05-02  Manta        0
```

Comment: Согласен, циклы нельзя использовать, тут бывает, негативно реагируют, если сам не предлагаешь решение, а только спрашиваешь.

Comment: Решение хорошее, что-то не додумался) Спасибо, посмотрю может ещё будут варианты, для саморазвития.